# Changing the image in a android gallery at certain times ... help

Tags: java, android, handler, image-gallery

My code here works fine . It changes  the image in my gallery at certain times , but i dont think this is the best approach , especially using thread.sleep() . How can i write a better code for that ? What am i missing ?
Thanks..

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        paraThread = true;
        workThread = new LooperFoto("MyWorkThread");
        workThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        workThread.start();
        super.onResume();
    }

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG, "thread state: " + workThread.getState());
    paraThread = false;
    workThread = null;
    super.onStop();
}


class LooperFoto extends HandlerThread {

    public LooperFoto(String name) {
        super(name);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (paraThread) {
            try {
                this.sleep(2000);
                mudaFoto.sendMessage(new Message());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}

Handler mudaFoto = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(thumbImgGallery.getAdapter()
                .getCount());
        thumbImgGallery.setSelection(randomIndex);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the thread that is .sleeping() is not your main (UI) thread, you should be fine. What are you worried about?

Comment: I was just a little concerned about thread.spleep() , but if it is not a problem i'm fine with it. Thanks

Comment: I think you just run the risk of your `Thread` being interrupted while it's sleeping.